# defining a function for the HANGMAN game using a loop in python

Tags: python, loops

i am a beginner in python and would appreciate your help.

I need to define a function(part of the HANGMAN GAME):

```
def show_hidden_word(secret_word, old_letters_guessed):
```

secret_word = a string of the word the player needs to guess.
old_letters_guessed = a list that contains the guessed letters by the player thus far.

the function needs to return a string made from letters and ' _ '. the string shows the letters from the  *old_letters_guessed* list that are in the *secret_word* string in their right place(index), and the rest of the letters the player has not guessed yet as a ' _ '.

**its supposed to look like this:**

```
>>> secret_word = "mammals"
>>> old_letters_guessed = ['s', 'p', 'j', 'i', 'm', 'k']
>>> print(show_hidden_word(secret_word, old_letters_guessed))
m _ m m _ _ s
```

this is what ive tried to do and it doesn't work (has to be done using for/ while loop):

```
def show_hidden_word(secret_word, old_letters_guessed):
 clue = ""
 for letter in secret_word:
  if letter in clue == True:
   clue + letter
   clue = clue + letter
  else:
   clue + '_'
   clue = '_'+ clue
 return clue
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: The "== True" in if-condition should be removed. Due to the operator priority it will always evaluate to false. The two lines with "something + something" don't do anything (result of addition is not used).

Comment: Generally, when asking here you shouldn't just write "doesn't work" but describe what happens, what should happen and show the full error message (if any) as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
def show_hidden_word(secret_word, old_letters_guessed):
  return " ".join([c if c in old_letters_guessed else "_" for c in secret_word])

secret_word = "mammals"
old_letters_guessed = ['s', 'p', 'j', 'i', 'm', 'k']
print(show_hidden_word(secret_word, old_letters_guessed))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your code:

- `clue = '_' + clue` should be `clue = clue + '_'`, since you want to *append* the underscore, not prepend it. You did it right for the other case, where you have `clue = clue + letter`
- The `if` condition is wrong in two ways:

  - It should not have the comparison with `True`, as this will *first* compare the string with `True`, and only then perform the `in` operator.
  - You don't want to check whether the letter is in `clue` (which is the result you are building), but whether it is in the old guesses.

  So it should be: `if letter in old_letters_guessed:`
- Not a blocking issue, but the stand-alone expressions `clue + letter` and `clue + '_'` do nothing useful. These lines of code can be removed.

If you fix those issues, your code will work.